# Use Saved xgboost Sklearn XGBClassifier Model State for prediction of new data

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, scikit-learn, xgboost

Currently I have a working xgboost XGBClassifier Model trained perfectly with good accuracy.

I have stored the model state (instance of the model) for new prediction on new python file by loading the state.

I am unable to load the labelencoder from the loaded model state to encode the new data.

If I am making use of new LabelEncoder() than my all data are encoded to 0 so I want to make use of the trained data labelEncoder value.

How I can achieve it?

My source code is:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from sklearn.externals import joblib
app=Flask(__name__)
import pandas as pd
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    model=joblib.load("Saved_Model.sav")

    print(model)
    //model is loaded successfully
    data=pd.read_json(request.data)
    print(data)
    col=data.columns
    //data also came perfectly
    encoder=model.__le__
    for i in range(0,len(TrainCols)):
       data[col[i]]=encoder.fit_transform(data[col[i]])
    prediction=model.predict(data.values)
```

Please help me to resolve my problem and also how can I get the list of parameters from the Model State?

Comment: Why are you using `fit_transform`? That will fit and transform at once. If your label encoder is already fitted, just use `transform` instead.